# How to add or remove a random number from an Array in Java?

Tags: java

A part of a small XO game I am making is that each time i press on a button, it turns into the sign X and then the computer will choose a random button to put the Sign O on.

The part that is confusing me is the random button the computer will choose. I have a `JButton` array with 9 buttons, but when the computer chooses, there will be a chance to choose a button that already has the sign X which will ruin the game.

Getting no duplicates is not a problem and is easily solved, but how can i give a button with the sign X a status that it is unavailable while generating random numbers? Here is my code so far:

In the actionperformed method:

```
if (e.getSource().equals(button1)) {

   button1.setIcon(X);
   xoro = true;
   button1.setEnabled(false);
   button1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
}
```

The method that executes random numbers and chooses the buttons:

```
void computer_play(JButton[] buttons, ImageIcon O, ImageIcon X)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(8);

    buttons[randomnumber].setIcon(O);
    buttons[randomnumber].setEnabled(false);


}
```

Comment: Your problem is pretty similar to getting no duplicates.

Comment: Since this is entirely random with no heuristic approach to "beating" the living player, you can simply take the list of buttons, use `Collections#shuffle` to randomize it, and pull the first result from that list repeatedly to get your next move. When a move is made, simply remove the played button from that list.

Comment: yeah no duplicates but that wouldn't solve the problem of choosing an already pressed button. Shuffle would solve 50% of the problem

Comment: Correct, which is why you remove pressed buttons from the duplicate list. Simply put, by removing the button when you press it, you can no longer select it as your next button. If you're really creative you could potentially even `#pop` the next button you're choosing off your random list, doing removal and selection in the same method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest keeping a separate array of available buttons, either by filtering the main array or by keeping a separate array up to date.  Then generate a random integer between 0 and the length of this smaller array.
Completely untested, uncompiled code below.

```
void computer_play(JButton[] buttons, ImageIcon O, ImageIcon X)
{
    JButton[] availableButtons = buttons.stream().filter((j) -> j.getIcon() == null).toArray(size -> new JButton[size]);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(availableButtons.length);

    availableButtons[randomnumber].setIcon(O);
    availableButtons[randomnumber].setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just fixed my issue, and would like to post the solution here for anyone that has some similar problem.

I created a a List that would contain 9 numbers from 0 to 8

```
List<Integer> randomize = new ArrayList<>();

 for(int i =0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            randomize.add(i);
        }
```

Then shufflle the list via `Collections.shuffle(randomize);`

Now we have 8 "random" numbers with no duplicates (problem 1 solved)

so now i would do something like `button[randomize.get(0)].setIcon(O)` 
and remove that index by randomize.remove(0). That will delete that selected number when i press the button to avoid duplicates.

When it comes to the buttons that the user plays, i would hold a record of the place of the button and remove that number from the list when it gets pressed with something like this:

```
randomlist.remove(new Integer(Arrays.asList(buttons).indexOf(button1)));
```

and now i'm done with my homework! Here is a picture of the program:

[XO in Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNzmv.png)